Get div content using id from one component to another component in Angular
I am in need of generate pdf in one component(billing.component). But the pdf content (div id='billcontent') is available in another component (billingpage.component).
Please someone help how to access the div element with id='billcontent' for pdf creation from billpage.component to billing.component.
The billing.component have button (Downloadpdf).
billing.component.html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="createPdf()">Download</button>

billing.component.ts
 import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-billing',
  templateUrl: './billing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./billing.component.css']
})
export class BillingComponent implements OnInit {

public createPdf() {
    var data = document.getElementById('billcontent') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
      var imgWidth = 208;
      var pageHeight = 295;
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;
      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
      let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
      var position = 0;
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
      pdf.save('new-file.pdf'); // Generated PDF
    });
  }
}

billpage.component.html
<div class="" id="billcontent">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>


what is the relationship between the two components?

sibling to other.

Create a behaviorSubject in a service, whenever the data is available to you, store the respective data in that behaviorSubject in the first component. For retrieving the data, subscribe to that behaviorSubject in another component and use the data as you wish.
export class PdfService {
  private pdfContentSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  pdfContent$ = this.pdfContentSource.asObservable();

  updatePdfContent(content: string) {
    this.pdfContentSource.next(content);
  }
}

Component 1:
const content = document.getElementById('billcontent').innerHTML;
this.pdfService.updatePdfContent(content);

Component 2:
this.pdfService.pdfContent$.subscribe(content => {
  if (content) {
    this.generatePdf(content);
  }
});

pdfService is the instance of PdfService, which you would define as an argument of the constructor.

The component 1 have trouble

If possible can you share in stackblitz
